# convolution: conv2 matlab to opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, convolution, cross-correlation

If i set input image and kernel in:

```
cv::Mat conv2D(cv::Mat input,cv::Mat kernel){
    printf("\nINPUT [ %d x %d ]\n",input.rows,input.cols);
    cout << input <<endl;
    printf("\nKERNEL [ %d x %d ]\n",kernel.rows,kernel.cols);
    cout << kernel <<endl;

    cv::Mat flipped_kernel;
    cv::Point2i pad;
    cv::Mat result;
    cv::Mat padded;
    cv::Point anchor(kernel.cols -kernel.cols/2 -1,kernel.rows -kernel.rows/2 -1 );
    cv::flip( kernel, flipped_kernel, -1 );
    printf("\nFLIPPED KERNEL [ %d x %d ]\n",flipped_kernel.rows,flipped_kernel.cols);
    cout << flipped_kernel <<endl;
    pad = cv::Point2i( kernel.cols - 1, kernel.rows - 1);
    cv::copyMakeBorder( input, padded, pad.y, pad.y, pad.x, pad.x, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,cv::Scalar(0) );
    cv::Rect region = cv::Rect( pad.x / 2, pad.y / 2, padded.cols - pad.x, padded.rows - pad.y);

    cv::filter2D( padded, result , padded.depth(), flipped_kernel, anchor, 0, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT );
    cv::Mat out = result( region );

    printf("\nOUT [ %d x %d ]\n",out.rows,out.cols);
    cout << out <<endl;
    return out;
}
```

Output is different to:

```
conv2(input,kernel)
```

Reading on the web someone tells that the flip is the error but others tell not. So i used a symmetric to rotation matrix as kernel and the result was still wrong. How i can perform a 2d convolution and 2d cross correlation in c++?

Comment: This `conv2(input,kernel)` is in Matlab? so you apparently want to do in C++ using OpenCV, what this `conv2` does in Matlab?

Comment: yes, it is a function of matlab that makes the convolution between two matrix

Comment: you know there are more parameters that be given to the conv2() function. Depending on what you give as the 3rd parameter, the result would be slightly different despite the same input matrices. You can decide, _'same', 'full' or 'valid'_ as the 3rd parameter. So try conv2(input, kernel, 'same'). Is your result the same to this?

Comment: No, result still different, with "same" the size of matrix returned change but the problem is on values of matrix returned. In opencv return some negative value. I'm trying to convert the matlab function in c++.

Comment: Can you give us a small sample `input` and `kernel` matrices that are giving you incorrect values in OpenCV? You shouldn't have to specify the anchor (just use `Point(-1,-1)`). Nor should you have to use `copyMakeBorder` (just specify `BORDER_CONSTANT` in `filter2D`).

Comment: I used a matrix 10x10 with all zeros exept to the border that has 1 and the corner that has 2. This matrix is used for kernel and for input

Answer (score 0):

The problema was that I passed opencv mats of type CV_32F and this give me wrong result, I converted images to CV_8UC1 with the method:

input.convertTo(input,CV_8UC1);
flipped_kernel.convertTo(input,CV_8UC1);

And change after the operation the type of output:

out.convertTo(input,CV_32F);

So the method works!